# laravel withinput not working for array

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-blade

View

```
<td>        
            {{Form::label('start_date', 'Start Date', array('class' => 'awesome'));}}
            <input type="date" name ="start_date" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Start Date" />
        </td>
        <td>    
            {{Form::label('end_date', 'End Date', array('class' => 'awesome'));}}
            <input type="date"  name ="end_date" class="input-block-level" placeholder="End Date" />
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>        
            {{ Form::text('answer[]', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Option')) }}
            {{ Form::text('answer[]', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Option')) }}
            {{ Form::text('answer[]', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Option')) }}
            {{ Form::text('answer[]', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Option')) }}
        </td>
   </tr>
```

here i have to do some validations and if error i need to redirect to the same page with preloaded data..

```
if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

**answer[]** being array is bottleneck here.. **withinput** is not working for array ..it shows the following error

```
ErrorException
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\app\views\questions\create.blade.php)
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem. Apparently, according to [this post](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2718), the solution is to manually add indexes to each of the inputs.

So try:

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
   {{ Form::text("answer[$i]", null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Option')) }}
}
```

Instead of using 'answer[]' for the input name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` or `for` loop before validation...

```
$data = Input::get('answer');

$rules = [];

foreach(Input::get('answer') as $k => $val){
   $rules[$k] = 'required';
}

$v = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```